# id invalid column in cursor though my table has column id

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My table has a defined column id.
Though the  same query runs  fin e independently,but when I try to declare it in a cursor, it shows invalid column.

```
declare 
  type PA_1 is record (PI number); 
  calc number; 
  row_container PA_1; 
begin 
  for row_container in 
  (
     select distict t1.pi , t2.id 
     from table1 t1, table2 t2 
     where t1.Pi=t2.pi
  ); 
  Loop 
    select calculation to calc 
    from table1 t1 
    where t1.pi=row_container.pi and t2.id=row_container.id;
  end loop; 
  commit; 
end;
```

the inner query runs fine otherwise. Please help

Comment: `declare
type PA_1 is record 
(PI number);
calc number;
row_container PA_1;
begin 
 for row_container in 
(select distict t1.pi , t2.id from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.Pi=t2.pi);
Loop
select calculation to calc 
from table1 t1 where t1.pi=row_container.pi
and t2.id=row_container.id;
end loop;
commit;
end;`

the inner query runs fine otherwise.
Please help

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors I am showing in my answer, you should no longer use this old join syntax. It was made redundant 25 years ago. Use `from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.Pi = t2.pi` instead.

Comment: What is this code block supposed to do by the way? Many tasks can be written in plain SQL and don't need PL/SQL.

Comment: Hi.. pardon me for the syntax errors.. submitted in a hurry.. the code block is a part of an update for a huge table.. I want to update the column "calc" using the value I get from join.though I could remove the "id" issue of no column, by declaring it as synonym.. I am getting too many values for "calc". the id is a unique column. still I am getting too many values

Comment: But if this is not the actual code you are having trouble with, it makes no sense posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Several syntax errors:

- First of all, you should remove the declaration for `row_container`. `for row_container in ()` makes this inplicitely (and your declaration with one column doesn't even match your query with two columns).
- `distict` should be `distinct`.
- Then remove the semicolon before the `Loop` keyword. It doesn't belong there.
- Then `select calculation to calc` should be `select calculation into calc`.
- Inside the loop you select from `table1` (which you call `t1` again), but your where clause contains `t2.id`, while there is no `t2` in that query.

And then: What is this routine supposed to do? It selects some value into the variable `calc`, but doesn't use it. So once it runs, it just doesn't do anything.